# Google App Script - How to set a trigger that is activated every time a specific cell in a specific column is filled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am doing an app with sheets api but some formulas of the sheet has some conflicts with the appended data by the api, so i need to do an autofill every time a new row is appended but i can´t set a trigger like that so i am forced to run the code every time i fill a new row. my actual code is here:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("I2").setFormula(`formula`);

  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2,9,lr-1);
  ss.getRange("I2").copyTo(fillDownRange);

}
```

Comment: Hi OP, you might want to check out Cooper's points as comments under my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This function `onEdit` is triggered everytime an edit to the sheet happens.

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  // if edited cell is "I2"
  if (row == 2 && col == 9) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

`myFunction` below is triggered everytime user inserts row (see `createTrigger` at the bottom). This is not the same as appending rows via api but you might be able to use this.

[image: insert row]

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // if user inserted row in sheets app
  if (e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
    // do something 
  }
}
```

You need to run `createTrigger` once to install the `onChange` trigger for `myFunction`.

```
function createTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

There are other available `changeType` [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for `onChange` trigger so you might want to check it out as that might be useful to you.

Comment: Triggers that respond to edits or changes generally only respond to user actions not changes caused by scripts or formulas. My guess is that to do with such a large server system would quickly bring the server to its knees.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thanks for your input here. Do you have any insights that can possibly help me to provide support to OP? A little hint would be very appreciated. What I'm thinking is that doing the code above that OP wrote to be run in api equivalent code, but not sure if that is possible.

Comment: I believe that the advantage of the of the installable trigger is handling permission but the triggers themselves still only respond to user actions.  Personally, I avoid the use of onEdit() and onChange() because they don't respond well for rapid changes and often miss triggers altogether.  So I normally opt for making my changes and clicking a button.  It's not automatic like Excel but it's simple and effect and I don't have to worry about the 30 second max execution times.  So I guess my answer is that there's  pros and cons to being on a server this is one of the cons.